# Get substring of length 1 or 2 for values in a column and put in single column in output?

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, case-when

I have a column that contains an alphanumeric code (elcode). I'm trying to create a new column in my select output that contains a value based on either the first one or two characters of the code field using `SUBSTR()` and `CASE WHEN` (TAXA_GROUP), but I can't figure out how to do this such that all the `CASE WHEN` results are in a single column.

Example:
Three example codes: AM1234, AR1357, PD9876. For the first two, I need to look at the first two characters. The first one would translate to 'mammal' in my output and the second one to 'reptile.' For the last one, I only need to look at the first character, which would translate to 'plant' in my output. In the whole dataset, there are 5 two-character substrings and 4 one-character substrings I need to evaluate.

I can produce something that contains two separate columns, one with the values resulting from evaluating those two-character substrings and the other with the values resulting from the one-character substrings, but I really want them all to go in the same final column. Here is what I'm doing so far:

```
SELECT EG.elcode
, CASE SUBSTR(EG.elcode, 1, 2) WHEN 'AM' THEN 'mammal'
WHEN 'AR' THEN 'reptile' END AS TAXA_GROUP
, CASE SUBSTR(EG.elcode, 1, 1) WHEN 'P' THEN 'plant' END AS TAXA_GROUP
```

The above produces output with two TAXA_GROUP columns, one populated with mammal, reptile, and null and the other populated with plant and null:

| elcode | TAXA_GROUP | TAXA_GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AM1234 | mammal | null |
| AR1357 | reptile | null |
| PD9876 | null | plant |

What I would like is to have one TAXA_GROUP column with the results of both of those `SUBSTR()` commands together.

| elcode | TAXA_GROUP |
| --- | --- |
| AM1234 | mammal |
| AR1357 | reptile |
| PD9876 | plant |

I tried concatenating the two columns, but I get an error:

```
SELECT EG.elcode
, CASE SUBSTR(EG.elcode, 1, 2) WHEN 'AM' THEN 'mammal'
WHEN 'AR' THEN 'reptile' END AS TAXA_GROUP1
, CASE SUBSTR(EG.elcode, 1, 1) WHEN 'P' THEN 'plant' END AS TAXA_GROUP2
, TAXA_GROUP1 || TAXA_GROUP2 AS TAXA_GROUP
Error: An error occurred while running query. ORA-00904: "TAXA_GROUP2": invalid identifier
```

In my searching on this site, I found similar questions, but most related to using `SUBSTR()` when you don't know how long the string is (requiring regex), which is not the case here.

Comment: Can you use global temporary tables. That way you can just join on the temp table which will have the codes and full name. Then your just joining against it using a wildcard against the code. You could also store this as a normal table if you plan on running it multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `LIKE`.  It is simpler:

```
select elcode,
       (case when elcode like 'AM%' then 'mammal'
             when elcode like 'AR%' then 'reptile'
             when elcode like 'P%'  then 'plant'
        end) taxa_group
from t;
```

But the point is that you want separate `case` conditions rather than just comparing one value.

Comment: Thank you, @GordonLinoff! `LIKE` does make things cleaner and more simple in this case. I don't know why I didn't think to use it from the get go.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data in lines #1 - 5; code that does the job begins at line #6.

```
SQL> with test (elcode) as
  2    (select 'AM1234' from dual union all
  3     select 'AR1357' from dual union all
  4     select 'PD9876' from dual
  5    )
  6  select elcode,
  7    case when substr(elcode, 2, 1) = 'M' then 'mammal'
  8         when substr(elcode, 2, 1) = 'R' then 'reptile'
  9         when substr(elcode, 1, 1) = 'P' then 'plant'
 10    end taxa_group
 11  from test;

ELCODE TAXA_GROUP
------ ----------
AM1234 mammal
AR1357 reptile
PD9876 plant

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot! I had never thought about what happens if the `CASE` scenario is before or after the `WHEN`. This is really useful, and I'm sure I'll need to do this with `SUBSTR()` someday. I only accepted @GordonLinoff's answer because in this situation, `LIKE` will work, and it is simpler.